# While loop keep repeating even though the criteria for it to break is met

Tags: loops, while-loop, break

```
fenced = '0' # Sets the criteria to an incorrect value
while fenced.lower() != 'fully' or 'partially' or 'none':
    fenced = input("Is the property fully fenced or partially fenced? (Answer 'Fully', 'Partially' or 'None') ")
    if fenced.lower() != 'fully' or 'partially' or 'none':
        print("Invalid Input. Please try again.")
    elif fenced.lower() == 'fully' or 'partially' or 'none':
        myfile.write("Fenced:\n" + str(fenced) + '\n')
        break
```

## The code is supposed to break the while loop after the user inputs "Fully", "Partially", or "None"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fenced = '0' # Sets the criteria to an incorrect value
while fenced.lower() != 'fully' or 'partially' or 'none':
 fenced = input("Is the property fully fenced or partially fenced? (Answer 'Fully', 'Partially' or 'None') ")
 if fenced.lower() != 'fully' and 'partially' and 'none':
    print("Invalid Input. Please try again.")
 elif fenced.lower() == 'fully' or 'partially' or 'none':
    myfile.write("Fenced:\n" + str(fenced) + '\n')
    break
```